# Придумати - слово питоме чи русизм?

Tags: росіянізм, дієслова

На сайті [Glosbe](https://ru.glosbe.com/ru/uk/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C) знайшла інформацію у російсько-українському словнику, що:

> **придумать - вигадувати**.

До цього часу була впевнена, що так справді є і слово придумати - русизм. Однак навіть у [словнику української мови за ред. Б. Грінченка](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/hrinchenko_slovar_ukrainskoi_movy/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) стаття все ж є!

На основі цього у мене виникає питання: слово придумати - слово питоме чи русизм?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Слово [придумати](http://sum.in.ua/s/prydumaty) знаходимо в CУМі:

> **ПРИДУ́МАТИ** див. **придумувати**.

Шукаємо за відсиланням:

> **ПРИДУМУВАТИ**, ую, уєш, недок., **ПРИДУМАТИ,** аю, аєш, док., перех.
>   1. Гадаючи, міркуючи, додумуватись до чого-небудь. 
>   //  Створювати або винаходити що-небудь таке, чого раніше не існувало. Їх [гостей] треба було почастувати надзвичайними яблуками і гарними піснями. 
>   //  Добирати потрібну фразу, слово і т. ін. 
>   //  Вигадувати, підшукувати для кого-небудь заняття, роботу, призначати комусь покарання і т. ін. 2. Вигадувати що-небудь неіснуюче, фантастичне. 
>   //  Створювати що-небудь в уяві. 
>   //  тільки док. Зробити або сказати що-небудь несподіване.

Ні в одному значенні немає позначки рідко, розм. і інших, які б могли поставити під сумнів походження цього слова.
 У [Словнику синонімів Л. Полюги](http://www.rozum.org.ua/index.php?a=term&d=23&t=572) знаходимо, що ці слова синоніми:

> **вигадувати**
>   (описувати те, чого немає) видумувати, **придумувати**, вимишляти, фантазувати, мудрувати, (на основі відомого) імпровізувати, розм.: плести, плескати. 
>    Також знаходимо ці слова як синоніми в іншому [Словнику синонімів](https://uk.worldwidedictionary.org/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8).
>     Отже, слово **придумувати** є питоме.